# Use ajax to update div tag by a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I want to update a div tag using AJAX. When the “Display” button is clicked on, an AJAX request is be made to the page specified in the drop down menu. The JSON object contained on that page will be displayed inside the div labeled “Other Page”. I have more than one JSON file that will be used. How do I update the div tag using the drop down menu?

JS:

```
function start() 
{
    $("#clickme").text("Calling server");

    $.ajax(
    {
        url : "mikey.json", 
        success : callbackFunction, 
        error : errorFunction, 
        dataType : 'json'
    });
}

function callbackFunction(data, info) 
{
    $("#clickme")
        .text("result: " + (data && data.name ? data.likes: "(No likes)"));
}

function errorFunction(data, info) 
{
    $("#clickme").text("error occurred:" + info);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="clickme" onclick="start()">Other page</div>
<form method="post" id="frm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Current roommate: </td>
            <td>
                <select name="room" id="rooms">
                    <option value="1" id="mi">Mikey</option>
                    <option value="2" id="sa">Sarah</option>
                    <option value="3" id="er">Sam</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Display" >
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How to update the div tag using the drop down??

Comment: can you provide a fiddle demonstrating the issue

Answer (score 0):

to trigger the event via dropdown list, you can simply do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rooms').on('change', function() {
        var data = $(this).val();  //you can retrieve the drop down list value
        start();
    });
}
```

and in the start method, you can call the ajax, then on the callback Success, you can modify the div. (as you have right now)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the values of the json in the select options, and pass those to the ajax function on submit.

HTML:

```
<div id="clickme">Other page</div>
<form method="post" id="frm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Current roommate: </td>
            <td>
                <select name="room" id="rooms">
                    <option value="mikey.json" id="mi">Mikey</option>
                    <option value="sarah.json" id="sa">Sarah</option>
                    <option value="sam.json" id="er">Sam</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Display">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#frm").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var jsonUrl = $("#rooms").val();
        $("#clickme").text("Calling Server");
        $.ajax({
            url : jsonUrl, 
            data: $("#frm").serialize(),
            dataType : 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#clickme").text("result: " + (data && data.name ? data.likes: "(No likes)"));
            }, 
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#clickme").text("error occurred:" + errorThrown);
            }, 
            dataType : 'json'
        });
    });
});
```

If you want the div to change as the person is clicking through the options (instead of waiting for them to submit the form), you can do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#rooms").change(function(){
        var jsonUrl = $(this).val();
        $("#clickme").text("Calling Server");
        $.ajax({
            url : jsonUrl, 
            data: $("#frm").serialize(),
            dataType : 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#clickme").text("result: " + (data && data.name ? data.likes: "(No likes)"));
            }, 
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#clickme").text("error occurred:" + errorThrown);
            }, 
            dataType : 'json'
        });
    });
});
```